# Dynamically load an object type and call its member function

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having the following classes -

```
public class A
{
   public class ChildClass
   {
      public string name;
      public string GetValue()
      {
      }
   }
}

public Class B
{
   string className = "ChildClass";

   //I want to create an object of ChildClass here 
   //and call the GetValue() method
}
```

How can I instantiate `ChildClass` in B and access its members with the class name I've?

**Updated Code -**

```
namespace LoadObjectByName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B obj = new B();
            obj.GetVal();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public class ChildClass
        {
            public string name;
            public string GetValue()
            {
                return "Invoked!";
            }
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string className = "ChildClass";
        public dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("A.ChildClass"));
        public dynamic GetVal()
        {
            return instance.GetValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is reflection, but I do not have the time ATM to work out the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var type = GetType(typeof(A).FullName+"+"+className);
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.GetValue();
```

Or:

```
var type = typeof(A).GetNestedType(className);
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.GetValue();
```

Comment: How can you call GetValue() using instance as instance is dynamic. The method GetValue() is not available to instance at compile time. I'm not able to compile the project.

Comment: `dynamic` is only available in .NET 4.0. I assumed, you are using a current version of .NET.

Comment: I'm afraid dynamic is available in .NET 3.5 also. However I changed the project version to .net 4.0 and compiled it and got the same problem. The point is how can instance know that it is pointing to ChildClass in the "compile time". Even the method "GetValue()" is not coming in VS 2010 intellisense. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NLV: [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) is not available in .NET 3.5, see [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx). Basically, all calls on a dynamic type are evaluated at runtime and unknown at compile time. This really is just a short hand syntax for manually using reflection to find `GetValue` on that class...

Comment: @NLV: If you really tried to compile the code in a .NET 4.0 solution and you are getting an error, please post it here.

Comment: Okie I got rid of the dynamic issue. Was missing an assembly reference to Microsoft.CSharp. But I'm getting a runtime ArgumentNullException error in the line `public dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("A.ChildClass"));`. Error is - Value cannot be null. Any ideas? I've updated my code.

Comment: @NLV: I think you need to qualify the class with the complete namespace. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Okay, I added the namespace and gave LoadObjectByName.A.ChildClass. Still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @NLV: Try this: `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("LoadObjectByName.A+ChildClass"));`. Be sure that `LoadObjectByName` is the complete namespace. Also note the `+`. That denotes a subclass. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Just perfect! It worked. Why do I need to put the +? Is that the syntax for accessing member functions?

Comment: @NLV: I updated my last comment. It is the syntax for a subclass.

Comment: Appreciate your extended help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please also see the updated answer. The ways used there are a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = Type.GetType("A").GetNestedType("ChildClass");
var inst = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] {});
Console.WriteLine(t.GetMethod("GetValue").Invoke(inst, new object[] {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamically call a method:**

```cs
  MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("GetValue");
  if (methodInfo != null)
  {
      methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { /* method arguments*/ });
  }
```

Comment: @sll: As the name of the child class is only known at runtime, this is not going to work.

Comment: Exactly. I just have the name of the class as "ChildClass".

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: why the name is only know at runtime? This is because it is a nested class?

Comment: @sll: This is, because the OP said it is like this. Just read his question again, please.

Comment: @sll B just knows the class name. A can have hundreds of classes. I'm working in MEF. So classes are loaded at runtime. So I don't know the child classes within the classes that are loaded in the runtime.

Comment: NLV - If you're working with MEF you really should be passing around interfaces instead, so that way you could care less about the actual class name (MEF will figure that out for you).

Comment: So just replace it by Type tp = Type.GetType("className");
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);

Comment: @sll: No, it doesn't work. instance will be of type `object`. You will then need to reflect on the method as well, you can't just call `instance.GetValue()`.

Comment: yep, you absolutely right, dynamic is works well for such cases, I'll modify my answer

Comment: @myermian Yes, I agree. It makes great sense. That should be simple to do. However I need to access the object right? I mean I read the class name from xml and need to access the member object.

Comment: @NLV: So you're mixing in your own reflection with MEF? That's a bit complicated. I think you need to rethink your architecture here. I'm not sure exactly what you're going for here, but if you're looking at selectively importing components then I'd use MEF still and then use reflection to add specific assemblies to your catalog. The specific assemblies should contain your exports.

Comment: @myermian No. Here is my problem. I'm having different parts and loading them in an asp.net page. Each part has some special controls which should be added in my page. I save all the special control settings for each part in xml. So when I'm building the page I load all my parts using MEF. But for each part I need to get its special control (reading from the xml) and get the control as object and add it to the page. For that I read the special control type name from the xml as string and use reflection to load it.